# Кастомные поля в laravel-admin

Tags: laravel, виджет

В проекте будут использоваться много разных виджетов(у каждого уникальные наборы полей, как статические, так и динамические), начал искать решения на подобие плагина custom fields, который используется в вордпресе и очень сильно был удивлен, что не нашел ничего похожего на ларавель. Может кто уже находил подобные пакеты, или может поделитесь как реализовываете свои виджеты?

P. S.
Пользуюсь laravel-admin, но если есть готовые решения на других админках, интересно будет посмотреть.

Comment: Нашел неплохое решение - https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence/wiki/Metable. Нормально работает с laravel-admin, только осталось найти решение как реализовать повторитель